# How to accept GET argument as complex object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, get

My input parameter looks like this:

`2Y` -  (2 years)
`28D` - (28 days)
`3M` - (3 months)

I want to accept argument like this:

```
public class InputDateInterval {
    private int count;
    private IntervalType intervalType;
    ...
}

public enum IntervalType {
    DAY("D"),
    MONTH("M"),
    YEAR("Y");

    private String sign;

    IntervalType(String sign) {
        this.sign = sign;
    }
```

Controller should look like this:

```
@GetMapping(...)
public Object(InputDateInterval idi, String anotherArgument, String...) {
    ....
}
```

How can I achieve it in spring mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You should combined all arguments into one Object rather different arguments. You should use POST method for this.

```
   @PostMapping("/someUri")
    public Object complexObjectMapping(RequestObject request) {
       //do processing for request object as needed
       return something;
    }
```

You should define a class for your complex request object which will consists all the possible arguments.

```
public class RequestObject{
      private InputDateInterval idi;
      private String anotherArgument;


      //getter and setter
    }
```

Comment: I have to use GET

Comment: Then try with @RequestParam

Comment: It will not help. You need to put logic of parsing somewhere in spring infrestructure

Comment: I think it will not why you are not using postmapping?

Comment: Because it has meaning of GET REST

Comment: from wiki: **The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect. (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.)[1] The W3C has published guidance principles on this distinction, saying, "Web application design should be informed by the above principles, but also by the relevant limitations."[15] See safe methods below.**

Comment: Agree. But you will not be able to use that kind of object this way. You can use @requestparam for string value and then convert it into your object

Comment: So in your opinion it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RequestBody`

```
@GetMapping
public void goGetStuff(@RequestBody InputDateInterval inputDateInterval) {
    ...
}
```

Still, I would recommend you to check your API design. I wouldn't have a GET with more than a couple of parameters

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to implement and register MvcArgumentResolver interface. You will have the access to http request object in your implementation, then implement your custom logic to map request parameters to your custom argument type.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/01/29/using-custom-arguments-in-spring-mvc-controllers/